# How do I get the data out of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this:

```
var myapp;
function Menu($scope){

    $.ajax({
          url: "/user.php",
          type: "POST",
          
          success: function(data){
              
          }
        });
        
}
```

How do I use the data out of the function scope?

Comment: who calls the Menu function. Your code or some framework?

Comment: framework calls that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having trouble because the ajax operation is asynchronous. This means that, after `$.ajax` is called, you can't control when exactly the response will arrive. In the mean time, your code keeps running normally, and if you try to use the response before it arrives, it will be empty.

You say in the comments that a framework calls your `Menu` function, so I'm assuming you can't control what parameters are passed to it. In this case, you should only use the data inside the `success` callback:

```
function Menu($scope){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            // USE data HERE
        }
    });
}
```

In case you can modify how `Menu` is called, you can pass a callback function to it, and let that manipulate the results:

```
function Menu($scope, ajaxCallback){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: ajaxCallback
    });
} 
// Define the callback where you will use the data
function processData(data) {
    // USE data HERE
}
// Call Menu passing the callback
Menu(whateverScopeIs, processData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable at the scope you need, and save the data to that variable. Or you can call a function and pass that data to it. 
For example:

```
function alertData(data){
  alert(data); // I can use the data here now!
}

var foo;
    $.ajax({
          url: "/user.php",
          type: "POST",

          success: function(data){
           alertData(data);
          }
        });

}
```

Comment: alert will be null as the success would not have been executed as it is async.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I thought alertData was to be passed as param, but I see you have used it as a method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable, assign data to it, and then use the global variable.

e.g.

```
var foo;
function bar(baz) {
    foo = baz;
}

bar("test");
alert(foo);
```